# How can I seperate the errors if there is a two forms on the same page. Laravel/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

I have a login page, which has login and registration forms on the same page. When registration fails it is sending me to login form and error appear in both form. I am using defaul authentication with "make:auth" command.

I don't want to change the name fields name. I tried to make login form hidden but it doesn't work. May be I couldn't.

My question is that how can I handle when registration fails, it should redirect me  to register form, not login form. And the errors should be spesific for each form.  Also how can I use error bags? I am new on laravel.

If you can explain to me in detail I will be grateful. Many thanks.

Here the view code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>Laravel</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700|Poppins:300,400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/vendor.bundle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.bundle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme-a.css">
</head>
<body id="auth_wrapper">
<div id="login_wrapper">

    <div id="login_content">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="assets/img/logo/ml-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo-img">
        </div>
        <h1 class="login-title">
            Sign In to your account
        </h1>
        <div class="login-body">

      <form id="login" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                         </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>

                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif

                </div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="forgot-pass pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
                <div class="checkbox inline-block">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" value="">
                        Remember Me
                    </label>
                </div>

                {{--<a href="/login" class="btn btn-info btn-block m-t-40">Sign In</a>--}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block m-t-40">Sign In</button>
                <div class="login-options">
                    <span>OR</span>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-facebook btn-block"><i class="zmdi zmdi-facebook"></i> Sign In with
                            Facebook
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-google btn-block"><i class="zmdi zmdi-google-plus"></i> Sign In with
                            Google
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-twitter btn-block"><i class="zmdi zmdi-twitter"></i> Sign In with Twitter
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

    </div>
    <div class="login-footer p-15">
        <p>
            Don't have an account? <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="update_url('login#register')" data-toggle="register">Create an account</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="register_wrapper">
        <ul class="card-actions icons right-top">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="register">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="assets/img/logo/ml-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo-img">
        </div>
        <h1 class="login-title">
            Create an account
        </h1>
        <div class="login-body">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-facebook btn-block"><i class="zmdi zmdi-facebook"></i> Sign Up with Facebook
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-google btn-block"><i class="zmdi zmdi-google-plus"></i> Sign Up with Google
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-twitter btn-block"><i class="zmdi zmdi-twitter"></i> Sign Up with Twitter
                </button>
            </div>

             <form id="register" class="clear-both" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                @csrf
                <h2 class="text-center p-t-20">
                    Or sign up below
                </h2>
                <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>

                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>

                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>

                <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                    <label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox inline-block">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" value="">
                        I agree to the <a href="javascript:void(0)">terms of services</a>
                    </label>
                </div>

                {{--<a href="/register" onclick="update_url('login#register')" class="btn btn-info btn-block m-t-40">Create my account</a>--}}
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block m-t-40">Create my account</button>
            </form>
           </div>
        <div class="login-footer p-15">
            <p>
                Already have an account? <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="register">Sign In</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="assets/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pass a variable that tells you which form was submitted and in blade use an if to show only on the correct form

Comment: Where should I pass the variable? can you please show me an example.

Comment: Post your registration controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently on a site I was building.  This may not be the best solution but the solution I came up with was to flash a variable to the session depending on the form that was submitted.  Then also check for that variable when checking for errors.

So in the method that handles the login method, add `session()->flash('form', 'login')`.  Then do something similar in the method that handles the register form.

Then in your view when checking for errors, you need to do something like...

```
@if ($errors->has('password') && session()->get('form') == 'login')
```

Comment: Sorry for this dumy question but where should I place this session. I didn't create any extra method. The login method has only constructor and trait. Should I override the AuthenticatesUsers/login method?

Comment: Yeah that would probably be the thing to do.  Since it's in a trait, it's not a traditional override though, you'd have to import the method from the trait with a different name using the `as` keyword.  You can see an example here if you aren't familiar.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php and search `Aliased_Talker`